# Translating JS function object with 'this' parameter to Fable

Tags: javascript, f#, fable-f#

I have a TypeScript config object that looks something like this:

```
interface Config {
    renderText?: ((this: {
        name: string;
    }, props: {
        prop1: Prop;
    }) => string) | null;
}
```

When using [ts2fable](https://fable.io/ts2fable/) I get the following automatic translation:

```ml
type [<AllowNullLiteral>] Config =
    abstract renderText: ({| name: string |} -> {| prop1: Prop |} -> string) option with get, set
```

However looking at the usage this doesn't seem correct. The `this` parameter should be implicitly available somehow.

```js
let config = {
  renderText(props) {
    return this.name
  }
}
```

What is the correct way to define this interface in F# Fable so that a `this` parameter is automatically available?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to represent this is to define your interface as a method rather than a function property:

```
type Config =
  abstract renderText: {| prop1: Prop |} -> string
```

In your implementation you access the `jsThis` value from `Fable.Core`:

```
{ new Config  with
    member this.renderText(props) =
      let this : {| name: string |} = jsThis
      this.name
}
```